# require.js POST request to spotify web api returning "Error parsing json"

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, spotify

According to [Spotify Web API Create Playlist](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/create-playlist/), once authorization is successful, a POST with the access_token and a few other parameters should create a new playlist for the user. 
The example CURL command in the link

```
curl -X POST "https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/wizzler/playlists"  
-H "Authorization: Bearer {your access token}"  
-H "Content-Type: application/json" --data "{\"name\":\"A New Playlist\", \"public\":false}"
```

This working fine for me. But when i run the following code from a nodejs application, using `request` library, the response stats `Error parsing json`.

What am i missing here?

Update: I tried changing `data` to `form` as per request.js examples. I also tried removing the stringify call, and passed the object directly. The error still persists.

```
var request = require('request');
var authOptions1 = {
    url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/' + username + '/playlists',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        'name': name,
        'public': false
    }),
    dataType:'json',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
};

console.log(authOptions1);

request.post(authOptions1, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
});
```

Comment: Remove `JSON.stringify()`; it should make the `data` property into JSON for you.

Comment: Tried this. It does not work. Same error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of using `data`, use `body`:

```
    var request = require('request');
    var authOptions1 = {
        url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/' + username + '/playlists',
        body: JSON.stringify({
            'name': name,
            'public': false
        }),
        dataType:'json',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
    };

    request.post(authOptions1, function(error, response, body) {
        console.log(body);
    });
```

that should make it.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/mikeal/request#requestoptions-callback

```
var authOptions1 = {
    url: 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/' + username + '/playlists',
    form: { // data = form
        'name': name,
        'public': false
    },
    json: true, // dataType: json = json: true
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
};

request.post(authOptions1, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
});
```

Comment: Do you use the express JSON parser ? `var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); app.use(bodyParser.json())`